# how to find some text in span class using bs4

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the names on the html page that is in each span tag, for example:

```
<span class="mn-person-info__name Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold-dense">
    Alex Jacob
  </span>
<span class="mn-person-info__name Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold-dense">
    Jim Bo
  </span>
```

This is my code:

```
names=[]  

spans = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'mn-person-info__name'})

for span in spans:
     names.append(span.string)
```

And then trying to get all the names and then store them in a list.

Comment: what errors did you come across?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "messagespam.py", line 17, in <module>
    spans = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'mn-person-info__name'})
TypeError: unbound method find_all() must be called with BeautifulSoup instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: Please post more code including how you create the `soup` variable.

Comment: Yes, what is soup, your problem may be with how you got soup

Comment: use `soup('span')`, your error says find all needs a soup instance, not a string

Comment: @supersam654 I did this: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

Comment: #<span class="mn-person-info__name Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold-dense">
      #  Geoffrey Forrest Hicks
     # </span>

 Now it works but I'm having a problem with this:                                                     
name=soup.find('span',{'class':'mn-person-info__name Sans-17px-black-85%\-semibold-dense'})
print name.text

Comment: can you post all of your code?

Comment: solved this =-)